# Inner join and selecting by category name in PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to PDO prepared statements and I have learned there are numerous ways to write prepared statements of which I prefer using:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username");
$query->execute(array(':username'=>$un));
```

It's fast and easy way and i want to just keep myself on this line. Now take a look at code below which is my question:

```
$query = ("SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, full_name, bio, posted, category 
FROM blogs INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id where 
category='cat1' OR category='cat2' OR category='cat3' ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 2");
```

Now this was actually written in `php` `mysqli` and now I want to change it to the way I have used above for PDO prepared statements without any `bindValue` or `bindParam` but as here I am calling data directly from database by category names itself so  `execute(array(':category'=>cat1));` is surely not going to work as we need a variable in place of `cat1` or will this work? If not how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use placeholders only if you have a variable to be used in the query.

If not - you don't need no placeholders at all, nor have to pass anything to `execute()`. In fact, you can use `query()` method instead of prepare/execute in this case.

Comment: thanks , just one more help `$query = ("SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, full_name, bio, posted, category FROM blogs INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id where category='Entertainment' OR category='Politics' OR category='Sports' OR category='Travel' ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 2"); foreach($db->query($query)as $row){ ` this code works, is this the way you were talking?

Answer (score -1):

Each param should be uniquely named otherwise you might get notices warning you about the fact and the number of placeholders must match the number of parameters in the `$params` array - so your query could be written like this. You cannot use `bound parameters` in the `order by` or `group by` clauses unfortunately.

```
$query = ("select b.`blogs_id`, b.`title`, b.`body`, b.`posted_by`, b.`full_name`, b.`bio`, b.`posted`, c.`category` 
    from `blogs` b 
    inner join `categories` c on c.`category_id`=b.`category_id`
    where `category`=:cat1 or `category`=:cat2 or `category`=:cat3 or `category`=:cat4
    order by `blogs_id` desc 
    limit 2");

$params=array(
    ':cat1' =>  $somevar,
    ':cat2' =>  'a string',
    ':cat3' =>  $anothervar,
    ':cat4' =>  'fashion'
);

/* with the actual values you specify */
$params=array(
    ':cat1' =>  'Entertainment',
    ':cat2' =>  'Politics',
    ':cat3' =>  'Sport',
    ':cat4' =>  'Travel'
);
```